# System only showing/using 3.1 GB of RAM on notebook with 4 GB

Tags: 16.04, ram

I have Ubuntu 16.04.1 (64 bits, Xenial Xerus) on an HP Compaq nx6320 notebook with 4 GB of RAM. However, the system monitor is displaying only 3.1 GB of RAM, as well as the lshw output. The BIOS menu however shows that there are indeed 4 GB of RAM installed. Any ideas?

Comment: I have 4 GB RAM and Ubuntu shows me 3.3 GB RAM. I dont have a graphic-card and some of the RAM is used for CPU-internal graphic-processor.This part of RAM is managed by BIOS and is not available for the operating system.

Comment: This computer I upgraded, it used to have 1GB of ram and back then it would display 990Mb.. I'm not sure it is taking a full Gb for the graphics processor. Is there a way to check that?

Comment: I have an option in my BIOS how much RAM to allocate for graphics, but i don't know if you have such option in your BIOS.

Comment: I just went searhing for that but I found nothing. Only RAM related option was "test memory" (which says all 4 gigs are working fine)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [the specs](https://www.manualslib.com/manual/624599/Hp-Compaq-Nx6320.html?page=2#manual) (see footnote):

> Above 3-GB, all memory may not be available due to system resource requirements.

(this warning is repeated on page 4)

Later it also states:

> Intel Graphics Media Accelerator 950 with up to 224-MB shared system memory